# Getting no space Error in AWS Linux instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am getting no space error in was Linux when I trying to git pull files. I don't know why the /dev/root file is so much big. Is there anyway to free up some space without deleting Linux packages like Node , composer , git etc ?

```
   root@ip-172-31-8-10:/# df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/root       7.7G  7.5G  276M  97% /
    devtmpfs        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
    tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs           393M  864K  393M   1% /run
    tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/loop0       34M   34M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
    /dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1997
    /dev/loop2       71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19647
    /dev/loop3       71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21029
    /dev/loop4       25M   25M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
    /dev/loop6       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12883
    /dev/loop5       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
    /dev/loop7       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12704
    tmpfs           393M     0  393M   0% /run/user/114
    tmpfs           393M     0  393M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: I am not preferring for extending the volume

Comment: Why don't you want to [expand the root volume](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-root-ebs-linux/)?

Comment: find out which files take up space and delete them

Answer (score 0):

You've configured an 8GB disk which is very small for most installs. You can do two things:

1. Expand the root volume. Pretty simple job to do on AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-root-ebs-linux/
2. Start removing files that take up space. The operating system itself takes up a significant amount of space unless you're running something super barebone like Alpine, but since you haven't specified which distro you're using, it's hard to give concrete suggestions here.